# My PHP code is not working properly

Tags: php, tags, switch-statement, case

I´m trying to do some program which would transfer hexa do binary. Problem is in changing of A,B,C,..,F to 10,11,12,...,15 so i can work with them as with numbers. I made this function:

```
function odstran_pismena($pole)
{
    $dlzka = count($pole);
    for ($i = 0; $i< $dlzka; $i++)
        switch ($pole[$i])
            {
                case 0: break;
                case 1: break;
                case 2: break;
                case 3: break;
                case 4: break;
                case 5: break;
                case 6: break;
                case 7: break;
                case 8: break;
                case 9: break;
                case ("A" || "a"): $pole[$i] = 10;
                                break;
                case ("B" || "b"): $pole[$i] = 11;
                                break;
                case ("C" || "c"): $pole[$i] = 12;
                                break;
                case ("D" || "d"): $pole[$i] = 13;
                                break;
                case ("E" || "e"): $pole[$i] = 14;
                                break;
                case ("F" || "f"): $pole[$i] = 15;
                                break;
                default: $pole[$i] = "ERROR";
                                break;
            }
    return $pole;
}
```

First i made array from string, and now i want to change letters to numbers.

I´m testing it with this string: `$test = "AbCdEf2345";`
I was expecting result 10 11 12 13 14 15 2 3 4 5 but all i have is 10 10 10 10 10 10 2 3 4 5

Am I doing some mystake?(Of course I am, but where?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

("A" || "a") evaluates to boolean value 'true', so all a to f will get caught by the case ("A" || "a" ) and result in 10.

Without using the hexdec() and with minimal change to your code:

```
function odstran_pismena($pole)
{
    $dlzka = count($pole);
    for ($i = 0; $i< $dlzka; $i++)
        switch ($pole[$i])
        {
            case 0: break;
            case 1: break;
            case 2: break;
            case 3: break;
            case 4: break;
            case 5: break;
            case 6: break;
            case 7: break;
            case 8: break;
            case 9: break;
            case "A":
            case "a": $pole[$i] = 10;
                            break;
            case "B":
            case "b": $pole[$i] = 11;
                            break;
            case "C":
            case "c": $pole[$i] = 12;
                            break;
            case "D": 
            case "d": $pole[$i] = 13;
                            break;
            case "E": 
            case  "e": $pole[$i] = 14;
                            break;
            case "F": 
            case "f": $pole[$i] = 15;
                            break;
            default: $pole[$i] = "ERROR";
                            break;
        }
     return $pole;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have specified `case ("A" || "a"): $pole[$i] = 10;` it evaluates to `true`. So all your chars matched against `true` returns true. for 'case' conditions avoid using expressions. Use the static values your comparing such as

```
case "A":
case "a":
    $pole[$i] = 10;
    break;
```

Comment: And can you explain me why it´s working this way? I´d be really thankfull :) and another question is why if put "case 0: break;" at the begin it will change nothing like it is true? :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to help you with that would be to use a strtolower:

```
switch(strtolower($pole[$i])) {

   case "a" :...
    break;
   case "b": ...
    break;

}
```

or simply, as the first line of your function:

```
$pole = strtolower($pole);
```

This way you won't have to bother with upper/lower casing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`hexdec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php) and replace you whole `for` loop with:

```
for ($i = 0; $i< $dlzka; $i++)
{
  $pole[$i] = hexdec($pole[$i]);
}
```

Note that you will receive a `0` for non-valid values so you might have to check for that separately if it can happen, using for example [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) on the original value.